# Is it valid, to update the state by mapping to new Objects

Tags: reactjs, state

**Let's take this Update State example:**

```
const initialState = [
    {id: 1, country: 'Austria'},
    {id: 2, country: 'Belgium'},
    {id: 3, country: 'Canada'},
  ];

  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);

  const updateState = () => {
    setData(prevState => {
      const newState = prevState.map(obj => {
        if (obj.id === 2) {
          return {...obj, country: 'Denmark'};
        }

        return obj;
      });

      return newState;
    });
  };
```

**1. Is it also valid to update the state like this? (First example)**

```
  const updateState = () => {
    const newState = data.map(obj => {
      if (obj.id === 2) {
        return {...obj, country: 'Denmark'};
      }
      return obj;
    });

    setData(newState);
  };
```

**2. Is it also valid to update the state like this? (Second example)**

```
  const updateState = () => {
    setData(prevState => {
      const newState = prevState.map(obj => {
        if (obj.id === 2) {
          let newObj = obj;
              newObj.country = 'Denmark'
          return newObj;
        }

        return obj;
      });

      return newState;
    });
  };
```

**3. Do this specific versions also have performance impacts? Which one is the best?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and the second example are perfectly valid. I would, however, suggest you to use the first one and I will explain why:

- With the first example you are using a callback as an argument of the function. And this form means that you are actually getting the last `data` state value (this is important because the state updates happen **asynchronously**). Whenever you need to update the state based on the previous value even React suggests to use the callback form to avoid side effects.

More infos here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

The third example is not valid because you are mutating directly the state. Something that in react is not allowed.

More infos here: https://dev.to/il3ven/common-error-accidentally-mutating-state-in-react-4ndg